# Trigger event on JavaFX service start

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to execute Java code when Service is started but I cannot find suitable Java method for this:

```
service.setOnRunning(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t)
    {
         Start some logic
    }
});

service.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t)
    {
         Stop some logic
    }
});
```

How I can call Java Method only once when Service is started?

Comment: Those methods do exist, what is your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily control `Service` start time, thus there is no special method.

Just add any code you want to be run at start to the `call` method:

```
private class MyService extends Service<Void> {

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                // "onStart" code
                System.out.println("Service started");
                // actual service code

                //do stuff
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```